# Reaction time not calculated correctly in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing an application that has three objects which are red. When they turn green the player has to tap as fast as he can on the screen and the reaction time is calculated. However I get the impression that the reaction time is wrong most of the times.

My code is the following:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class light : MonoBehaviour
{


    public Button theButton; 
    public ColorBlock theColor;

    public float time_left;
    public GameObject Replay_Game_Button;
    public GameObject TimeText;
    public GameObject ErrorText;
    public bool open=false;
    public float startTime;
    public float endTime;
    public bool set=false;
    public int counter;



    // Start is called before the first frame update

    void Start()
    {
        time_left=Random.Range(0.0f, 3.0f);
        theButton = GetComponent<Button>();
        theColor=GetComponent<Button>().colors;
        theColor.normalColor = Color.red;
        theButton.colors=theColor;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        time_left -= Time.deltaTime;
        if ( time_left < 0 && set==false)
        {
            if (set==false) {
                startTime=Time.time;
                set=true;
            }
            open=true;
            theColor.normalColor=Color.green;
            theButton.colors = theColor;
        }
        if (/*Input.touchCount>0*/Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)  && open==false){
            displayError();
            return;
        }
        else if (/*Input.touchCount>0*/Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && open==true){
            displayTime();
            return;
        }
    }

    public void displayTime(){
        endTime=Time.time-startTime;
        counter= PlayerPrefs.GetInt("counter");
        if (counter==5){
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Time",endTime);
        }
        else if (counter==4){
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Time2",endTime);
        }
        else if (counter==3){
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Time3",endTime);
        }
        else if (counter==2){
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Time4",endTime);
        }
        else if (counter==1){
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Time5",endTime);
        }
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Replay");
    }

    public void displayError(){
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Error Scene");
    }

}
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Actually your end time just working fine, where dou you check your endTime ?

Comment: @Arkin Erkan I don't understand what do you mean check it? I just print in the next scene ("Replay") to the user

Comment: how far off do you think it is?

Comment: @vasmos I found the mistake, I was using the script on 3 different objects and not on game manager, resulting in three different times, of which the last one was kept

Answer (score 0):

Things to try buff the min on this up

```
   time_left=Random.Range(0.0f, 3.0f);
```

it can return 0 seconds

it looks like

```
if ( time_left < 0 && set==false)
        {
            if (set==false) {
                startTime=Time.time;
                set=true;
            }
            open=true;
            theColor.normalColor=Color.green;
            theButton.colors = theColor;
```

Should just be in the bottom of your start function like this, and removed from update loop

```
  //...
  startTime=Time.time;
  set=true;
  open=true;
  theColor.normalColor=Color.green;
  theButton.colors = theColor;
```